# Nodejs - Unable to fetch data of files from google drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-file-stream

I am trying to fetch data of a file from google drive.
For which I have done all the steps mentioned in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Also I am able to get the list of files in the drive. But I am not understanding how to get the data inside the files. I have tried the below code which I found in google, but I am getting the response as `undefined`.

Here is my code

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const zlib = require("zlib");
const creds = require("../../../credentials.json")
const getfilelist = require("google-drive-getfilelist");
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.

  authorize(creds, listFiles);

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    credentials.client_id, credentials.client_secret, credentials.redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const topFolderId = "1MTER3d8AVkpw0-_32xpxzZtyuP8iMH66"; // Please set the top folder ID.
getfilelist.GetFileList(
  {
    auth: auth,
    fields: "files(*)",
    id: topFolderId,
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const fileList = res.fileList.flatMap(({ files }) => files);
    fileList.map((file) => {
      console.log('iiiiii',file)
      downloadFile(auth, file.id)
    });
  }
);
}

function downloadFile(auth, fileId) {const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
console.log('fileIdfileId',fileId)
let progress = 0;
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
},
function(err, { data }) {
  console.log('actual data', data);
  var bdata = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8')
  console.log('buffered data', bdata)
})




}
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
};
```

Near the code  `console.log('actual data',bdata)` I am getting the output something like `PK"♠�S↕word/numbering.xml��MN�0►�O�↔"��$§ ¶5� 6�♥���X�=��I��q��R$��U��������Kɠ�h♣��ˈ♦\3Ȅ.R���x"�uTgT��)9rK���u��J�9�}�Gh�(���9���e%W�.�p�9���/§�Ce▬♀��N�¶�↑���t↑HI�:�►♂%↑��ܝ$ �`���
���Jv�*ŵ;;�ȥ�☺�-��=Mͥ�b�C�♫Q+��k�¶�♀i��dk�f♠�qk��][∟�q4a�'Ġ���OϾ‼E�▲0�t\�♠���vF�↓ga�F�қ�#���.�y^ꍘ��+�W�
PI‼C⌂h☺=♣PK"♠�S◄word/settings.xml���n�0♀ǟ`�►���I6↑uzX�����=#ɶ►}A����'ǖդ@�f�H⌂�?�♀M?>�§|q��2%K��R��↕+�d]�?�?����:�♦���Dgj����cWX���♂O��►�D�s�H↕�����♦8⌂5u"�∟[��Jhp��8s�$O�-→1�D��ňX`

and near the console.log('buffered data', bdata) I am getting the output as `<Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 22 06 ef bf bd 53 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 77 6f 72 64 2f 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 69 6e 67 2e 78 6d 6c ... 15880 more bytes>`

How do I get the actual text from the file.

Can some one please help

Comment: If you remove the callback in the third parameter and you log the response on the first `.on`, do you get anything?

Comment: Its already part of your code your downloading it to sample.txt   **var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./sample.txt');**   are you saying that sample.txt is empty?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, it is empty

Comment: @Iamblichus Which third parameter? Can you please be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are authorizing the application with `drive.metadata.readonly` scope, which does not give you access to the file content and doesn't let you download it.

#### Solution:

Remove the `token.json` that you generated, modify the `SCOPES` in your code with an appropriate scope like `drive` and go through authorization again:

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
```

#### Reference:

- [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing)

Comment: This is quite close. I am able to get the list, but I am getting 403 error. code: 403, errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'fileNotExportable', message: 'Export only supports Docs Editors files.' } ] } . Also I have made changes to my code and posted the new code in my question

Comment: @Saisri You are getting this error precisely because of the changes you made to your code. As the error you are getting says, `files.export` is used for downloading Google Docs files (see [Download a Google Workspace Document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_document)). For regular files, you have to use `files.get` (see [Download a file stored on Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)). Therefore, roll back those changes and use `files.get` as you were using originally.

Comment: I am getting data in below format. How do I convert to text format

�♥���X�=��I��q��R$��U��������Kɠ�h♣��ˈ♦\3Ȅ.R���x"�uTgT��)9rK���u��J�9�}�Gh�(���9���e%W�.�p�9���/§�Ce▬♀��N�¶�↑���t↑HI�:�►♂%↑��ܝ$ �`���
���Jv�*ŵ;;�ȥ�☺�-��=Mͥ�b�C�♫Q+��k�¶�♀i��dk�f♠�qk��][∟�q4a�'Ġ���OϾ‼E�▲0�t\�♠���vF�↓ga�F�қ�#���.�y^ꍘ��+�W�

Comment: @Saisri If you just want to retrieve the text content, and you don't want to actually download the file, just remove the second parameter from `files.get`: `{responseType: 'stream'}` (since you edited your code so many times, I'm unsure whether you did that already).

Comment: I have edited the question with my current code where I have replaced files.export with files.get also I have updated my current issue in the question. Can you please look into it

Comment: Here is my new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289842/fetching-data-from-google-drive-using-node-js and the previous answer was helpful and I accepted it.

Comment: @Saisri `the previous answer was helpful and I accepted it` You didn't accept it. To accept an answer, you need to click the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons next to the answer ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry, I did now

Answer (score 0):

Try following the code from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

```
function downloadFile(auth, fileId) {
    const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v3',
        auth
    });
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./sample.txt');
    drive.files.get({
            fileId: fileId,
            alt: 'media'
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            console.log('Done');
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error during download', err);
        })
        .pipe(dest);
}
```

Comment: @DalmTo I am getting the error as TypeError: drive.files.get(...).on is not a function

Comment: your existing code uses drive.files.get which implys that you have placed it in the wrong spot.

Comment: @DalmTo Where did I do the mistake? Where should the code be placed?

Comment: replace your downloadFile with this method and try that.

Comment: @DalmTo I replaced your code. On replacing I got the error 
TypeError: drive.files.get(...).on